# How to use a system path to load xml file in XElement in windows phone

Tags: c#, xml, linq, file, windows-phone-8

I am working with a windows phone8 application. I have a file stored at a particular location in device and i want to open it with XElement. If i give path to that file it says uri should be relative and see webclient for more details. I know that it cant take xmlReader cause its not availabe in windows phone so that leaves me with two options to open a file with XElement which are String uri *which windows phone libraries treat as a url* and TextReader.

Can some one please give me an idea how to load my file in XElement directly for reading and writing purpose. Please help me out on this. or Any other way to handle my xml files.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

The first approach I'd suggest is opening the path as a stream, and then use [`XDocument.Load(Stream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838349). (There's a similar method for `XElement`, but I typically use `XDocument` when I'm loading a whole document, to make it clear that that's what I'm doing.)

That may cause issues if the document has relative DTD links or something similar, but in the vast majority of cases it will work.

Likewise you can save to a stream too.

Comment: strangely XDocument.Load(Stream) is not availabe may be because i am using .Net Framework 4.0 i need to upgrade it to 4.5. Meanwhile can you please show me a tutorial for this. It'd be great help.

Comment: @user3641909: `XDocument.Load(Stream)` is available in .NET 4 as far as I can tell... (I'm surprised it wasn't in .NET 3.5, in fact.) There's `Load(TextReader)` as well, which you can use if you know the encoding beforehand so can hook up a `StreamReader` - is *that* available to you?

Comment: Its not available in .net 4 cause i am using VS 2012 on windows 8 or may be my system is a bit weirdo (which is true to an extent). 

Text reader is available to me so i'll have to user text reader to load file and text write to save file every time i need to do an operation.

Comment: @user3641909: Windows 8, or Windows Phone 8? They're very different - although the documentation claims it's available on both anyway...

Comment: i upgraded my .net framework to 4.5.2 but still VS is not showing xdocument.load(Stream) method. What is happening.

Comment: @user3641909: I assume you *are* using it as a static method? `var doc = XDocument.Load(stream)`?

Comment: amm yes. Is it not static.

Comment: @user3641909: No, it *is* static - the code I've given should be fine. It's hard to tell what's wrong without more context, I'm afraid.